# Garbage collector usage when upgrade from Java 6 + Tomcat 6 to Java 8 + Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

We are upgrading from Java 6 and Tomcat 6 to Java 1.8.0_45 and Tomcat 8.0.23, Linux servers, 64 bits.
I'm comparing memory usage and I'm facing a weird behaviour.

This is how Eden Space looks with Java 8 in Tomcat 8 with no traffic, just started and idle:
[image]

And this is how it looks with Java 6, standard to me:
[image: java 6 tomcat 6]

Both JVMs are configured the same way, basically:

`XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Xms768m -Xmx2048m -Xmn400m`

With Java 8 and Tomcat 8 minor GC are almost always running and tomcat log show this:

`1301,121: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 408960K->352K(409088K)] 1126151K->717559K(1915392K), 0,0093033 secs] [Times: user=0,02 sys=0,00, real=0,01 secs]`

Do you know some special configuration for JVM 8 or something I have to do to have the same behaviour than before?

**EDIT:**

After 30 min, Eden Space is:

[image]

Comment: In java-8 You could use `G1GC` instead of `ParallelGC`. This *could* improve your performance. Atleast go for `CMS`. Also, you should perhaps set the number of threads to be used for GC

Comment: thanks @TheLostMind but the question is, why behaviour is not the same than before?

Comment: You should not expect similar behavior across JVMs. Too many things could have changed that lead to such output

Comment: Yeah your are right, but at least i could expect a 'normal' behavior beacuse it is unusable at the moment

Comment: @FranMontero How did you determine that it's not "normal" what you're seeing on Java 8?

Comment: Too much has changed wrt memory (where objects stay, Permgen etc) from jdk6 to jdk8. So, I am not sure if you should actually compare Memory allocation / GC behavior for these versions

Comment: I'm comparing them because my production servers are running java 6 very well and same environment with java 8 and tomcat 8 is running out of eden space (0 to 400MB) continously with no traffic. There must be a leak somewhere that is producing that. Maybe is a tomcat thing, i don`t know

Comment: @FranMontero - Then I suggest changing the GC rather then checking why you are having the leak.

Comment: Sure, i'll try that @TheLostMind thanks

Comment: @TheLostMind i've tryed all GCs but same behaviour. It seems that minor GC is being triggered even  when there is free space in eden :/

Comment: a larger chunk of the GC logs would be useful.

Comment: Same trace again and again, minor collections occur almost every second @the8472

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like this is a problem with the application itself in the first place. You said the application is idle but the graph shows (even in Java 6) that the application is allocating 400MB of memory and freeing it up twice a second. It really doesn't sound like this application is idle.

Possibly your application creates many objects (even when it's "idle"). GC and Optimizer were changed in Java 8 since Java 6. This could explain the different graphs.

But anyway, I would start with trying to find out why the application is not idle when you expect it to be idle.

Comment: Sorry, graph with Java 6 is actual production environment with traffic. Please take a look at the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392402/memory-allocation-behaviour-with-java-1-8-in-tomcat-6-and-tomcat-8